# Cassandra append-only timeseries modelling/querying

Tags: database, cassandra, cql, finance

I am modelling a financial stock price storage in Cassandra, where I need to cater for retrospective changes.
An append only database is what came to mind.

`CREATE TABLE historical_data (
          ticker text,
          eoddate timestamp,
          price double,
          created timestamp,
          PRIMARY KEY(ticker, eoddate)
        ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (eoddate DESC);"""`

eg a record might be: 
ticker=AAPL, eoddate=2016-09-28, price=123.4, created=2016-09-28 16:30:00

A day later, there was a retro data fix, I'd insert another record
ticker=AAPL, eoddate=2016-09-28, price=120.9, created=2016-09-29 09:00:00

What is the best way to model/query this data, if I'd like to get the latest series for AAPL (ie filtering the first value)?
in SQL I could write a parition query.  How about in CQL ?

Or should the filter be applied at the application level?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, to model correctly, we need some more informations and more precisely : cardinalities. How many ticker at most (estimation of course) ? How many updates per ticker ? 1 per day / hour / minutes ? The data retention strategy (i suppose in your case, data will never be deleted). And does records in your case will be mutable or immutable ?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to create a immutable, append only schema model in Cassandra.  The finance end-of-day above is just an example.

For discussion's sake, I'd assume 30k tickers, and each ticker most likely have one end-of-day value per day, except for the rare occasion retrospective changes (eg, one value update per week), which I'd insert the new value.

The challenge is finding ways to efficiently query the data.  If it is SQL, I'd do a 'select from partition by EOD (pick latest one out per partition)'.

How would I do something similar in CQL ?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly your need, your table is good.
With this schema, you can run query like :

```
SELECT price
FROM historical_data
WHERE ticker = 'AAPL'
LIMIT 1;
```

It will return the last price for ticker AAPL.

The `CLUSTERING ORDER BY` clause order your data physically in descending order for a specific `ticker`, it wont order the whole table. So this query should be enough.